# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll not included in Build Folder

Tags: c#, excel

I write a Console Application with C#, .NET Framework 4.0.

This project reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`.

When i build project successful, but in build folder not included Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.

When i change to .NET 2.0 and build it, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll` is included!

But i want to build and run my program in .NET 4.0.

I use VS 2010.

Show me how to fix.

Comment: so just copy it to the build folder manually

Comment: i manual copied, but when run program in other Computer, error occurred at `new Excel.Application();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if the Copy Local is set to true for the referenced DLL.

You will first need to set "Embed Interop Types" property to false. Then you can set the 
Copy Local" property to true.

[image]

Embed Interop Types property was [introduced in VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/samng/archive/2010/01/24/the-pain-of-deploying-primary-interop-assemblies.aspx) to remove the dependency of deploying PIAs.